# How make a pause inside a loop?

Tags: python

I've connected a 20*4 LCD screen on my Raspberry Pi. It works.

I have a code to screen several sentences and loop them

But I can't find a proper way to pause each 4 sentences and to clear the screen before next 4 sentences

Here is the actual code (edited because while pasting I had an indentation change)

```
  def typewriter_like(sentence, lcd_line, delay=0.7):
      for i,letter in enumerate(sentence):
          lcd_byte(lcd_line, LCD_CMD)
          lcd_string(sentence[:i+1],1)
          time.sleep(delay)

      mots = (("EXAMPLE", "EXAMPLES", "EXAMPLESS", "EXAMPLESSS"),
              ("ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"),
              ("LULU", "FIFI", "RIRI", "TATA"))
      lcds = (0x80, 0xC0, 0x94, 0xD4)
      list(zip(mots,lcds))
      [(('EXAMPLE', 'EXAMPLES', 'EXAMPLESS', 'EXAMPLESSS'),128),(('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE','FOUR'),192),(('LULU', 'FIFI', 'RIRI', 'TATA'),148)]

   while True:
     for mot in mots:
         for word, lcd in zip(mot, lcds):
             typewriter_like(word, lcd)
        time.sleep(10)

        for lcd in lcds:
                lcd_byte(lcd, LCD_CMD)
                lcd_string("",2)

        time.sleep(4)
```

What I want is to pause the first 4 words... Then erase everything (all cleared) before print the 4 next words

EXAMPLE
EXAMPLES
EXAMPLESS
EXAMPLESSS

stay printed for 10 seconds
Then all cleared

ONE
TWO
THREE
FOUR ...

stay printed for 10 seconds

etc...

And at the end a loop...
Could someone help me ?

Comment: Just add those `time.sleep()` calls in the correct context.  Looks like maybe all you need is to indent `time.sleep(10)` once to put it in the right block.  same w/`time.sleep(4)`.

Comment: You're calling `typewriter_like(word, lcd)` in the middle of `typewriter_like`. That can't be what you want. That means you'll get to the first step of the first loop, then call yourself and start all over again. Not to mention that `lcd` isn't defined anywhere, so it's probably some global from elsewhere in your code, and you're passing the first `word` as the new `sentence`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify the indenting

```
  while True:
    for mot in mots:
        for word, lcd in zip(mot, lcds):
            typewriter_like(word, lcd)
        time.sleep(10)

        for word, lcd in zip(mot, lcds):
            typewriter_like(" " * len(word), lcd)
```

Comment: I've tried but it's weird :no pause after the 4 sentences and it's not cleared before screening the next sentences. What I'd like is to pause 10 seconds and clear all the screen before the next 4 sentences

Comment: @brako. You can't clear the screen by writing empty strings, you can print spaces over the top though

Comment: Thanks Gnibbler... Now it pause as I want... But still I can't clear ALL the screen before printing next sentence. Isn't that possible ?

Comment: @brako, try `typewriter_like(" " * 20, lcd)`

Comment: I've tried but it's not cleared completely before next 4 sentences. I have this : EXAMPLE / EXAMPLES / EXAMPLESS / EXAMPLESSS... The words pause correctly but remain printed when the next sentences arrive : ONE / EXAMPLES / EXAMPLESS /EXAMPLESSS ... It's only at the end of a cycle that everything's cleared before the loop